# Flutter Draggablescrollablesheet header/indicator

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm trying to implement a DraggableScrollable Sheet in flutter. I want something like GoogleMaps explore, but I am not able to create this indicator, that the sheet is scrollable, which goes away when I scrolled all the way up.

Furthermore the Google Maps Sheet have a borderRadius on the topLeft and topRight corner, which dissolve when scrolled all the way up.